# How to show element from function which returns array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I should get announcement's i element's x. In the end of the code, I've added loop which have to set left and top properties to the pin. Please help me!)
Here is my code:

```
    var announcement = function () {
      var result = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        result.push({
          "location": {
            "x": Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200) + 1,
            "y": Math.floor(Math.random() * (630 - 130) ) + 130
          }
        })
      }

      return result;
    }

    var map = document.querySelector(".map");
    var pinTemplate = document.querySelector("#pin").content.querySelector(".map__pin");        

    for (var i = 0; i < announcement().length - 1; i++) {
      var pin = pinTemplate.cloneNode(true);
      pin.setAttribute("style", "left: " + announcement()[i].x + "top: " + announcement()[i].y);
      document.querySelector(".map__pins").appendChild(pin);

      console.log(announcement()[i].x);
    }
```

Comment: See the simplified answer and short as well for you. Let me know.

Comment: I think you're looking for announcement()[i][x], but I'm struggling to follow your question,

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote and accept as "the" answer below: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can do like this to get element and display in div or any element you want.

Please see the working example.

```js
 var announcement = function () {
      var result = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        result.push({
          "location": {
            "x": Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200) + 1,
            "y": Math.floor(Math.random() * (630 - 130) ) + 130
          }
        })
      }
      return result;
    }
    
    
    var node = document.createElement("div");
   announcement().forEach(function (element) {
     var textnode = document.createTextNode('left: '+element.location.x+' - top:  '+element.location.y+' ');
     node.appendChild(textnode);
     document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
   })
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  
</div>
```